# Doctrine Inheritance: Discriminator from Entity attribute and not table column?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

Using Doctrine2 inheritance, I want a slight variation so that the discriminator is not based on a column (from the mapped table), but rather on an Entity's attribute. The code would look like this:

(p.s I know there's nothing like **@DiscriminatorAttribute** in Doctrine, I'm just asking about an eventual workaround to "implement it")

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorAttribute(name="shopType", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"local" = "LocalShop", "foreign" = "ForeignShop"})
 */
class Shop
{
    const TYPE_LOCAL="local";
    const TYPE_FOREIGN="foreign";

    protected $shopType;
    // ...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class LocalShop extends Shop
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->shopType=Shop::TYPE_LOCAL;
    }
    // ...
}
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class ForeignShop extends Shop
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->shopType=Shop::TYPE_FOREIGN;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Why would you want this? It'd be a million times neater (& less coupled) to simply add a method shopType() which returns either of those constants.

Comment: I'm working on a huge old DB with lots of legacy inside, and the logic from each ShopType is completely different. So I'm seeking to hide this chaos through ORM, a step behind further migration to a neat DB..

Comment: In that case, at the very least I'd map the property as, well, property. After that you could check if you can simply make the column it's mapped to, the discriminator column. If doctrine does not allow doing that, add a custom migration that duplicates the column contents and weep :)

Comment: Sounds rational, that's what first came to my mind among other solutions. The constraint is I SHALL NOT write any migrations or change anything regarding the current DB architecture.

Comment: Discriminator has to be a column or the queries won't work.  If you can't add one then you can't use Doctrine inheritance mapping.

Comment: Definitely yes, the question is is there a workaround, common use or any other way to obtain something like described in the question, and why do you think it hasn't been implemented for example?

Comment: As far as the why goes, the Doctrine ORM was designed for simple CRUD type databases.  Complex legacy stuff is pretty much off the table.  Too many variations to try and support.

Comment: @Cerad Doctrine can certainly be used to map legacy codebases, so long as there's some kind of models to be mapped. The real reason Doctrine doesn't want to use properties as discriminator keys is twofold: properties belong to the domain and can be changed at runtime, making database syncing very challenging - second, it's a mapping mechanism and should not have a place in the domain at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that `shopType` is a rather static property (in the sense that it will always be the same for all instances of a class) you can simply define the `shopType` as default for the property, and use the existing column as discriminator column:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="shopType", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"local" = "LocalShop", "foreign" = "ForeignShop"})
 */
class Shop
{
    protected const TYPE_LOCAL = 'local';
    protected const TYPE_FOREIGN = 'foreign';

    // ...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class LocalShop extends Shop
{
    protected $shopType = Shop::TYPE_LOCAL;
    // ...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class ForeignShop extends Shop
{
    protected $shopType = Shop::TYPE_FOREIGN;
    // ...
}
```

Doctrine's hydrators will take a new instance of your class, which gets instantiated with all default values applied, and then write all the fetched information from the database to the mapped properties.

Since your property has the expected value in the defaults, and is not mapped, its correct default value will not be changed by the hydration process and have the expected value, even when fetched from the database.

In that process, the constructor is not called (Entities are either cloned or produced by Reflection's [newInstanceWithoutConstructor](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstancewithoutconstructor.php)), which is why the original code did not work.